# DocumentApp for Google Apps Script not returning all attributes of an element?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

When I attempt to get attributes from an element using the getAttributes() method from the Google Apps Script DocumentApp library for a Google Doc, not all attributes show up; specifically the GLYPH_TYPE attribute for a listItem element.

Due to the lack of functionality within Google Docs for checklists, I'm writing a code script to automatically calculate the percent completion of a list based on the symbol present of each list item belonging to a list. In order to do this, I am retrieving all listItems relevant to a listID, and then attempting to check their GLYPH_TYPE attribute in order to differentiate which items have been completed (which the user indicates by clicking the symbol left of the list item and changing it to a checkmark). It is the latter that I am having issues with; when I call getAttributes() for either the Paragraph or the listItem object for the list item, GLYPH_TYPE isn't present at all.

Here's a method where I am simply trying to extract the GLYPH_TYPE attribute for a listItem;

```
function getGlyphTypeFromListItem(documentId){
  var doc = 
  DocumentApp.openById("1mzVQUccSH_suf8KoTkbVN4XjIOcfbYDuie3GV_M1Fg8");
  var body = doc.getBody();
  Logger.log(body.getParagraphs()[0].getAttributes());
  Logger.log(body.getParagraphs() 
  [0].findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM).getElement()
  .getAttributes()); 
}
```

When I run this method I get the responses:

```
[19-01-20 18:22:02:242 MST] {FONT_SIZE=11, ITALIC=true, HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT=null, INDENT_END=null, INDENT_START=144.0,LINE_SPACING=null, LINK_URL=null, UNDERLINE=true, 
BACKGROUND_COLOR=null, INDENT_FIRST_LINE=126.0, LEFT_TO_RIGHT=true, 
SPACING_BEFORE=null, HEADING=Normal, SPACING_AFTER=null, 
STRIKETHROUGH=null, FOREGROUND_COLOR=null, BOLD=true, 
FONT_FAMILY=Roboto Condensed}
[19-01-20 18:30:21:253 MST] {FONT_SIZE=11, ITALIC=true, 
HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT=null, INDENT_END=null, INDENT_START=144.0, 
LINE_SPACING=null, LINK_URL=null, UNDERLINE=true, BACKGROUND_COLOR=null, 
INDENT_FIRST_LINE=126.0, LEFT_TO_RIGHT=true, SPACING_BEFORE=null, 
HEADING=Normal, SPACING_AFTER=null, STRIKETHROUGH=null, FOREGROUND_COLOR=null, 
BOLD=true, FONT_FAMILY=Roboto Condensed}
```

As you can see, GLYPH_TYPE is completely absent from both of the logs; is there something I'm missing? Also, have any of you found a more intuitive way to track the completion of "checklists" within Google Docs?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google documentation says that the "Paragraph" `getAtributes` method [(doc)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#getattributes) "retrieves the element's attributes. The result is an object containing a property for each valid element attribute where each property name corresponds to an item in the DocumentApp.Attribute enumeration." `GLYPH_TYPE` is recorded as one of the properties of "[Enum Attribute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute)".

I agree with the OP that the `GLYPH TYPE` is not reported when a paragraph is analysed.
However if the Paragraph Type = `DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM`, *then* `getAttributes` **does** report the `GLYPH_TYPE`, as well as some additional data (Refer image below). It is difficult to say whether there is a bug in the Google code, or (perhaps) an error in the documentation.

So far as the OP code is concerned, I got the same results.

But it's interesting to note a ListItem is returned by `getParagraphs` but a ListItem is NOT a 'paragraph'. ("A Paragraph may contain Equation, Footnote, HorizontalRule, InlineDrawing, InlineImage, PageBreak, and Text elements." ([docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph))). The `getParagraphs` method "retrieves all the Paragraphs contained in the section (**including ListItems**)"  ([docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getparagraphs)). It's an odd, almost contradictory result, but I think this may be a reason why the OP's code was unsuccessful.

---

This was my code (adapted from the OP).

```
function so54282539() {

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();

  // variable to count the list#
  var listcounter = 0;

  // get the Paragraphs
  var paras = doc.getParagraphs();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: paras = "+paras);//DEBUG
  Logger.log("DEBUG:Number of paragraphs: " + paras.length); //DEBUG

  // get the List Items
  var lists = doc.getListItems();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Lists: "+lists);//DEBUG
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Number of lists: " + lists.length); //DEBUG
  Logger.log("     "); //DEBUG

  //Loop through the Paragraphs (i)
  for (var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {

    var mytypeof = paras[i].getType();
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Paragraph#i=" + (i + 1) + ", Type: " + mytypeof); //DEBUG

    // if thgis parapgraph is a list item, then get more information
    if (mytypeof === DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {

      var paraattributes = paras[i].getAttributes();

      // list the paragraph attributes
      for (var key in paraattributes) {
        if (paraattributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          Logger.log("Paragraph Attribute: " + key + " -> " + paraattributes[key]);
        }
      }

      // List the GLPH TYPE
      Logger.log("Glyph: " + lists[listcounter].getGlyphType());
      var otherattributes = lists[listcounter].getAttributes();

      // List the List_Item Attributes
      for (var listkey in otherattributes) {
        if (otherattributes.hasOwnProperty(listkey)) {
          Logger.log("List_Item Attribute: " + listkey + " -> " + otherattributes[listkey]);
        }
      }
      listcounter = listcounter + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Typical Attribute comparison - Paragraph vs List_Item
[image: Typical Attribute comparison - Paragraph vs List_Item]

---

List_Item Attributes
[image: List_Item Attributes]

---

Document layout
[image: Document layout]

Comment: Calling getAttributes() on a paragraph that does have element type LIST_ITEM doesn't return all attributes, but getting that same paragraph with the getListItems() method does reveal glyph type. I would argue that there is something wrong with Google's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
function getGlyphType(){
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var children=body.getNumChildren();
  var gA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<children;i++){
    var child=body.getChild(i);
    if(child.getType()==DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
      gA.push(child.asListItem().getAttributes()['GLYPH_TYPE']);
    }
    var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(gA.join(', '));
    DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Info')
  }
}
```

I could get whether its a number or a bullet but I couldn't determine what type of bullet it was.